# How to get notification from MetaMask either transaction was successful or not in React app?

Tags: blockchain, metamask, dapps, react

I am working on a dapp, and I want the functionality that when some user initiates a transaction then page will update itself after some time(when we get the response that either transaction was successful or not). But how can I get that notification from MetaMask or form web3js(as I'm working with web3js).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. I'm using ethers and not web3js but the idea should be the same.

In this example the user clicks a button to send tokens somewhere. The state variable updated with `setWaitingForTx` can be used to update the page after the tx completes.

```js
const handleClick = async () => {
  console.log("Clicked Send Tx")
  
  tokenContract.transfer(
    to,
    amount
  ).then((tx) => {
    setWaitingForTx(true)  // a state variable useful in other functions
    tx.wait().then((receipt) => {
      setWaitingForTx(false)
      console.log("Transfer Successful!")
    }).catch((err) => {
      setWaitingForTx(false)
      console.log("handleClick Error: ", err)
      console.log("Transfer Failed!")
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    setWaitingForTx(false)
    console.log("handleClick Error: ", err)
    if (err.code === -32603) {
      // specific error from blockchain if it exists
      // may not work with providers different from Metamask
      console.log(err.data.message)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For web3.js, your method calls return a promise. So you should be able to use .then() to process the result of the transaction, or the .catch block to catch a failed transaction.

For my use case (using react on the front end) I typically create a hook that has a function that handles the transaction and returns a promise, then in whatever component i'm using I handle the result of the promise.

Here is an example:

```
const useTxHook = () => { 
  const processTx = async () => { 
    try { 
     return await contract.methods.someMethod().send()
    } catch(e) {  
      return e
    }
  }  
  return processTx; 
}

const SomeComponent = () => { 
  const {processTx} = useTxHook();
  const click = () => {
    processTx()
     .then((d) => console.log(d))
     .catch((e) => console.log(e))
  }
  return (<button onClick={click}>Process Tx</button>)}
```